# regex single quotes just between select and from without changing start and end quotes

Tags: php, sql, regex, oracle

i'm using php and i want to replace single quotes in a oracle sql query.

i have something like this :

`select 'this is test' for 'stack overflow'' , 'another' single quote was around here' from testtable where id='test' and another='test2'`

i am using oracle so the escape character is double single quote.

my issue is to find single quotes just only between `select` and `from` statement, replacing shouldn't remove the first single quote at start and end of each field.

answer should be something like this

`select 'this is test'' for ''stack overflow''' , 'another'' single quote was around here' from testtable where id='test' and another='test2'`

the number of fields can be vary. in my example it had two field each one contain single quote. but sometimes fields contain quote and sometimes not, sometimes they come after each other and some times not.

i tired different regexp. try to come up with a solution but no luck

so my question is how do i implement this? which php funciton or what regex?

Comment: I don't know why you have to do this. Usually, there will be interface to SQL database that escapes the data for you. If you are not already using them then please port your code base.

Comment: we are using custom made adodb library that it provide quote escape only if the string provided. it add `q'` at start and one `'` at end but here my problem is i have a full sql querry and in this case cant use that code. this is our adodb [qstr](http://phplens.com/adodb/reference.functions.qstr.html)

Comment: So you have the whole query sent to you over the net and you are required to execute it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do what you want directly.
If you for example have `'field one', 'field' two'` it could be interpreted as either `'field one', 'field'' two'` or `'field one '', ''field'' two'`.

You might want to try something like this instead, if possible:

```
//First put the field names in an array $fields
...

//Then you create the query string like this
$sql = "select '" . implode("', '", str_replace("'", "''", $fields) ) . "' from testtable where id='test' and another='test2'";
```

Comment: the problem is i'm getting the query and i have to execute it. all query is written with different ppl in different departments. i don't have fileds to implode it

Comment: I don't think you can create a non-ambiguous regexp without some more information about the queries. If, for example, you know that there is no commas in the field names and no single quote in the names/values after `from` then a regexp can be created.

Comment: Consider for example `select 'a', 'b' from 'a', 'b' from 'a', 'b'`, which is very ambiguous